# React - passing props down to child syntax issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I'm very new to React and am trying to get an app started.  In my main App.js file I am setting up some dummy props data to pass down to the child component `Schedule`.  I am trying to use arrow functions vs class or functions to create the components.  I'm sure I'm missing something very basic.  I'm gettting a lot of ESLint errors about a missing comma and "Types are not supported by current Javascript version."

App.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import Schedule from './components/home/SchedulePage';

const App = () => (
        orders: [
            {
                id: 1,
                title: 'First Order',
                desc: 'This order is for .'
            },
            {
                id: 2,
                title: 'Second Order',
                desc: 'This order is for .'
            },
            {
                id: 3,
                title: 'Third Order',
                desc: 'This order is for .'
            },
            {
                id: 4,
                title: 'Fourth Order',
                desc: 'This order is for .'
            },
            {
                id: 5,
                title: 'Fifth Order',
                desc: 'This order is for .'
            }
        ]

    return (
        <div>
            <Schedule/>
        </div>
    );
);

export default App;
```

I'm also not sure how to send the `orders` into `Schedule`.

Comment: `<Schedule orders={orders}/>` And since `orders` isn't part of the `state` you can declare it outside your component. `orders` will be acessible inside `Schedule` via `props.orders`

Comment: `const App = () => (` should be `const App = () => {` , you are using wrong braces

Comment: I've gone through plenty of video and text tutorials :)  I need to get my hands dirty and start coding to make it really sink in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have incorrect syntax in component body. It should be like

```js
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import Schedule from './components/home/SchedulePage';
const orders = [
    {
        id: 1,
        title: 'First Order',
        desc: 'This order is for .'
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        title: 'Second Order',
        desc: 'This order is for .'
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        title: 'Third Order',
        desc: 'This order is for .'
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        title: 'Fourth Order',
        desc: 'This order is for .'
    },
    {
        id: 5,
        title: 'Fifth Order',
        desc: 'This order is for .'
    }
];
        
const App = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <Schedule orders={orders} />
        </div>
    );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: Right, it should be `const orders = [`

Answer (score 1):

You can pass down your `orders` to `Schedule` like this:

`<Schedule orders={orders} />`

You can name this whatever you want, let's say you wanted to name this prop `banana` you could do this:

`<Schedule banana={orders} />`

---

You can then access your `orders` in your `Schedule` component like this:

```
const Schedule = (props) => {
  console.log(props.orders)
}
```

This reflects the name you gave it in the first part, so again, if you named it `banana` you access it like this:

```
const Schedule = (props) => {
  console.log(props.banana)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Markup:

```
<Schedule orders={orders} />
```

You can then acesss your `orders` props via `props.orders` in your `Schedule` component.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can pass data from parent to child component

```
let orders = [
  {
      id: 1,
      title: 'First Order',
      desc: 'This order is for .'
  },
  {
      id: 2,
      title: 'Second Order',
      desc: 'This order is for .'
  },
  {
      id: 3,
      title: 'Third Order',
      desc: 'This order is for .'
  },
  {
      id: 4,
      title: 'Fourth Order',
      desc: 'This order is for .'
  },
  {
      id: 5,
      title: 'Fifth Order',
      desc: 'This order is for .'
  }
]

const App = () => (
  <div>
      <Schedule orders={orders}/>
  </div>
);
const Schedule=({orders})=>{
  return <div>Schedule</div>
}
```

you can iterate and pass every object to child component

```
const App = () => (
  <div>
    {orders.map(order => (
      <Schedule key={order.id} order={order}/>
    ))}
  </div>
);
const Schedule = ({ order }) => {
  return (
    <div key={order.id}>
      <p>
        {order.title}, {order.desc}
      </p>
    </div>
  );
};
```